# Whats the difference between PostSharp and Castle Dynamic Proxy?

Tags: c#, aop, postsharp, castle-dynamicproxy

Just wondering what the main differences are between these libraries, how they differ in features and functionality.

Hoping for more information than I could find with a Google query...

Answer (score 16):

The main difference is when the AOP code is incorporated into your program

"Postsharp works by weaving at compile time"

Dynamic Proxy generates lightweight .NET proxies on the fly at runtime.

see: [Applying AOP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62798/applying-aop)

Answer (score 8):

http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2007/07/02/7-Approaches-for-AOP-in-.Net.aspx