# PostSharp , PDB Debugging and Referenced Assemblies

Tags: debugging, postsharp, pdb-files

When using PostSharp with a Referenced Assembly with proper PDB info( checked with chkmatch), it seems strange that the debug info gets lost by VStudio build and post compile process and I get the following error by using chkmatch to compare the assembly after the vstudio build.

Error: Debug information not found in the executable.

So it doesn't step into for debugging into this assembly.

Does Post Sharp properly writes back the Assemblies without destroying the PDB location offset info as I saw no valid offset info in the written back into DLL by PostSharp using Hex Editor and What's the workaround for this ?

Comment: Please use this answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31299157/dotpeek-pdb-generation-for-assemblies-without-debug-directory
It will solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, PostSharp writes back PDB files (with proper transformations), so there should be no problem with Visual Studio. I don't know what could be wrong; maybe you could try to load them manually (in the Module window of VS) and see what happens.